# SUMIFS with multiple criteria variable

Tags: excel, sumifs

I just discovered [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/sumifs-with-multiple-criteria-and-or-logic) that I can use SUMIFS with multiple criterias, which is really cool.

But there is any way to set a variable to the criterias?

Example: instead of writting

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{"red","blue"}))
```

I would like to put the text "red" on the cell A1 and write:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,{A1,"blue"}))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your range of values is A1:A2, try using that as the third (Criteria1) argument, and pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,A1:A2))
```

This will produce an array formula and you should see brackets surround the formula afterwards.

```
{=SUM(SUMIFS(sum_range,criteria_range,A1:A2))}
```

Comment: this was really great